# save index of multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

Following multidimensional array is created dynamically.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[2][1]">
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[2][2]"> 

 ...........................................

<input type="checkbox" name="menu[2][x]">
```

How to store first index and second index as separate variable ? for example

```
foreach($_POST['menu'] as $arr){
//$a = $arr['first index'];
//$b = $arr['second index']
}
```

Comment: what you exactly want ?? explain clearly...!

Comment: every time you have fix index like menu[2] ?

Comment: Please explain with more detail and what out put you want??

Comment: @DsRaj, yes `menu[2]` is fix, only second index would changed `menu[2][i++]`

Comment: foreach($_POST['menu']['2'] as $key => $arr){
update like this and use $key

Comment: which type of output you need ...?

Comment: If the index `2` fixed means then answer will be `$a = $_POST['menu'][2][array_keys($_POST['menu'][2])[0]];

  $b = $_POST['menu'][2][array_keys(array_reverse($_POST['menu'][2],true))[0]];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST['menu']);
        foreach ($_POST['menu'] as $key => $value) {
            $index1[] = $key;
            foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
                $index2[]=$key1;
            }
        }
        print_r($index1);
        print_r($index2);
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu[][]">1<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu[][]">2<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu[][]">3<br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First off, you should include an explanation for your code. Also, that would produce an array looking like. `$menu[0][0]`, `$menu[1][0]`, `$menu[2][0]` and so on. Then the second depth would then be quite useless. and it would be easier to just do : `$menu[]` instead.

Comment: @Dr. Strange, Thanks very much, your php code works well, though I don't change html. But why your answer had been down voted ?

Comment: Or a person *with* coding knowledge did not like your code-only answer and found it not useful for lacking an explanation or for being inefficient. (Not me, by the way.)

Comment: but person like dislike doesn't matter code is working for questioner is main point so next time down voter please remember this...!

Comment: @Yunnosch And why don't this hypothetical genius downvoter dont post what he/she thinks is correct or missing explanations?

Comment: Because that is the concept of StackOverflow. Voting is important, both ways. Voting down has a high risk of retaliation, which scares people off voting. So voting is anonymous. Yes you are right, downvoting **with** an explaining comment is the even better feedback, but anonymous downvotes are appreciated, too. Many users have made bad experiences with explaining and have stopped.

Comment: Making the asker happy is by the way **not** the purpose of StackOveflow and therefor not a reason not to downvote. The goal is making a good answer, which helps many people and thereby also makes the asker happy. That would be a reason to upvote. I admit that I don't have this kind of coding knowledge so I do not judge the efficiency of your code. But I do see a lack of explanation.

Comment: I do not understand your last comment. Would you like to elaborate?

Comment: @Yunnosch, I think It is my weakness that question have to be clear.  Because of frustrating coding environment and all efforts go in vain , the moment comes where problem can't be explained clearly, and after solution found from expert guys like you, It becomes easy to debug where is problem and learn lesson. Be relax friends..happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = $_POST['menu'][2][1];

$b = $_POST['menu'][2][2];
```

-Edit: is this what you want:

```
foreach($_POST['menu'][2] as $k => $v){
 $a = $v;
  if(isset( $_POST['menu'][2][$k+1]))
   $b = $_POST['menu'][2][$k+1];
}
```

Comment: That's only true if the OP uses `$menu[2][]`. The OP seem to be setting the keys manually.

Comment: It's also true if the OP uses $menu[2][0]. Be careful using the word **ONLY**

Comment: @AmrBerag, I think it is not possible to store variable as `$a = $_POST['menu'][2][2]` because this is generated dynamically, it is not manual entry.

Comment: @AmrBerag - Sure, but I think you and the OP understand what I mean.  Specially since in the OP's code, it starts with 1.